# If/Then (# to Text) With Multiple Number Ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am using Excel and trying to create a formula. Part of the formula works, the next doesn't. I'll explain.

Column P is "BPM" (Beats Per Minute) and will have a numeric value, which will be entered manually.

Column Q is "Speed/Tempo" and this will have a text value that I'd like to auto-populate based on the numeric data entered into column P.

So if column P is a number 1-44, Q equals the text "Variable Tempo"; 45-69 Q="Slow Tempo"; 70-94 Q="Slow-Medium/Mid Tempo"; and there are a few other number ranges with a text value associated.

To achieve the value in Q, I use `=IF(P1>=1,IF(P1<=44,"Variable Tempo")`

I can then use the "&" to separate copy/pastes of the formula but with the additional number/text values, so

`=IF(P571>=1,IF(P571<=44,"Variable Tempo")&IF(P571>=45,IF(P571<=69,"Slow Tempo")`

but here's the problem with the end result. Insteade of showing "Slow Tempo", the result I'm getting is "FALSESlow Tempo".

How do I correct this?

Comment: Dave, I appreciate that and realize it's a risk. However, reading through posts to try to find an answer (trying to respect regulars and not duplicate threads/questions), I find a lot of regulars always tells the newbs the same thing "There are x number of threads on this, please don't create redundant threads". This happens all the time... So I was simply trying to nip that in the bud. Sorry if it turned you off. I don't think it's that deep, is it? Your help would be appreciated. Blessings-

Comment: I also think you probably want to use `AND` instead of `&`

Comment: Dave, I am only now learning how to use the site... Bear with me brother.

Comment: And, no, I don't think you're wrong that it doesn't hurt to have duplicate questions. But again, so often the reaction is far from "Thanks for the dupe, bro! And by the way check this out!" I don't know what "voted close" means but (genuinely) thanks for letting me know... Honestly it seems sort of ridiculous that someone would be shutdown or their question would go unanswered because they entered a community brand new as a first timer and make a mistake in etiquette... So... with that, I'll try "AND". :)

Comment: Please delete your comments on this post, people don't need to read our discussion :) I have removed my -1

Answer (score 0):

I belive the issue is first with your formula, you need to use `AND` like this

```
=IF(AND(P3>=1,P3<=44),"Variable Tempo",IF(AND(P3>=45,P3<=69),"Slow Tempo",IF(AND(P3>=70,P3<=94),"Slow-Medium/MidTempo","Not detected")))
```

Instead of showing "Not detected" you may want to simply show "" (to show nothing)

Copy and paste that down in colum Q (updating the P3 to P1 or what ever row is your starting row)

Screen shot (click to expand):
[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you, Dave. And thanks again for helping assimilate me to the proper process here. I reviewed your edit of my post and will do better next time.

Comment: Remember, if the answer is right (and only if it is) then please mark it as such(the green tick). This will help others who read this question. With more [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you'll also be able to upvote as well

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "FALSE" because you haven't close the previous **IF** function.
Try this..

`=IF(P571>=1,IF(P571<=44,"Variable Tempo"),IF(P571>=45,IF(P571<=69,"Slow Tempo"),"Not Found"))`